# Time Series Insights is burning money. Is it safe to delete it?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-timeseries-insights

I see that I'm being charged daily for Time Series Insights. I don't think I'm using it and I see that I can delete it in the Azure portal, but is it safe to do so and will it save money?

Comment: That is a strange question to ask the community. You have probably created it for a reason. We don't know that reason. You say you don't *think* you are using it but how should *we* know? And yes, deleting it will if course save you money as you do not have to pay for something that is not there anymore.

Comment: No, I didn't create it directly. It was created when I created the IoT hub, along with a ton of other resources. I don't think I will be using the Time Series Insights so I would like to delete it but I was just wondering if deleting it would make the entire IoT solution stop working.

Comment: No it won't stop your IoT Solution. Think of Time Series Insight as a database for time based analysis of the data coming in from the IoT hub. If you are not interested in that you can delete it without any device failing to send data to the hub.